# Sharing shared preference with other app is giving old/cached values

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have two apps ,lets say A and B. App A has a shared pref which is created as world readable so that app B can access it.
When i try to access the App A's shared pref value from app B for the very first time,  it gives correct result. But the problem come when i change the shared pref value of app A and then open app B to check the updated shared pref it gives the same old value. And surprisingly when i force close the app B from settings--> apps and reopen the app B it gives the correct updated value of app A's shared pref.

What is the problem with accessing shared pref a application when it is WORLD_READABLE.

Below is the source code of **app B** when i am accessing the Shared pref of **app A**.

```
private boolean isDAEnabled() throws SecurityException {
    Context context = null;
    try {
        context = createPackageContext(APP_A_PACKAGE_NAME, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (context == null) {
        throw new SecurityException("can not read shared pref of old DAE");
    }

    SharedPreferences oldDaPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences
            (A_SHAREDPREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    int what = oldDaPrefs.getInt(A_PREF_ENGINE_STATE, 4);
    Log.d(TAG, "What is value "+ what);
    return  what == ENABLE_ENGINE; // ENABLE_ENGINE IS == 0

}
```

And Below is the code where i am changing the shared prefs of **App A**

```
private void setEnginePreference(boolean engineStatus) {
    mPreferenceEditor = mPreference.edit();
    if(engineStatus){
        mPreferenceEditor.putInt(Constants.PREF_ENGINE_STATE, ENABLE_ENGINE);
    } else {
        mPreferenceEditor.putInt(Constants.PREF_ENGINE_STATE, DISABLE_ENGINE);
    }
    mPreferenceEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: See my answer below it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
private void setEnginePreference(boolean engineStatus) {
    mPreferenceEditor = mPreference.edit();
    if(engineStatus){
        mPreferenceEditor.putInt(Constants.PREF_ENGINE_STATE, ENABLE_ENGINE);
    } else {
        mPreferenceEditor.putInt(Constants.PREF_ENGINE_STATE, DISABLE_ENGINE);
    }
    mPreferenceEditor.commit();
}
```

To :

```
private void setEnginePreference(boolean engineStatus) {
    mPreferenceEditor = mPreference.edit();
    if(engineStatus){
        mPreferenceEditor.putInt(Constants.PREF_ENGINE_STATE, ENABLE_ENGINE);
    } else {
        mPreferenceEditor.putInt(Constants.PREF_ENGINE_STATE, DISABLE_ENGINE);
    }
    mPreferenceEditor.apply();
}
```

Comment: Not working ! i have changed commit to apply. But same problem.

Comment: Try to use shared pref change listener in APP B and see once

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as i have figured out the solution.

I found in the [blog](https://michiganlabs.com/android/development/2016/02/02/accessing-android-shared-preferences-multiple-processes/)  that i can use MODE_MULTI_PROCESS while accessing the shared prefs of the different app(i.e. **app A** in my case). However, as of API Level 23 (OS version 6.0), Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is deprecated. But my requirement was only to support API level 23 so it was good for me.

Here is the change i had to make

```
private boolean isDAEnabled() throws SecurityException {
Context context = null;
try {
    context = createPackageContext(APP_A_PACKAGE_NAME, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (context == null) {
    throw new SecurityException("can not read shared pref of old DAE");
}

SharedPreferences oldDaPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences
        (A_SHAREDPREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

int what = oldDaPrefs.getInt(A_PREF_ENGINE_STATE, 4);
Log.d(TAG, "What is value "+ what);
return  what == ENABLE_ENGINE; // ENABLE_ENGINE IS == 0}
```

I hope that it will help others.